# How can I print the log4j output into a log file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

I am pretty new in **log4j** and I have the following problem.

Into a simple Java application I am using log4j that actually correctly print the logging output into the console (the shell), I am using this configuration into the **log4j.properties** file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender X:
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, consoleAppender

## Set the appender named X to be a console appender:
log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# Define the layout for console Appender appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

It works fine but I need to do the following things:

1. Instead print the logging output into the console I want that it is written inside a **mylog.log** file. How can I do it?
2. Actually the logging line have the following shape:

   ```
   21406 [main] DEBUG utility.Mailer  - (mailer) MESSAGGIO INVIATO
   ```

   what exactly represent the **21406** string at the beginning of this logging line? How can I print the current date and time at the beginning of the logging line?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a file appender to your log4j config file

**E.g**:

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=D:/logs/file.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ContextPrinting=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a file appender, in addition to your stdout (console) appender.
Of course, you should probably use the same pattern you use for your console.
One such example would be:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, stdout, R

log4j.appender.R = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %5p [%t] (%F <<%M>>\:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.File = /var/www/porject-name/www/logs/project-name.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize = 100000KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Re. 1
As Salah and Schaka suggested - you need to define a file appender.

Re. 2
In your console appender you've defined a pattern that starts with `%-4r` where `r` means:

> Used to output the number of milliseconds elapsed from the
>   construction of the layout until the creation of the logging event.

and the `-4` part means "right padding if less than 4 digits".
To display current date and time use `%d` pattern.

Source: [PatternLayout JavaDoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)